# How to use function variable of one class to another class in Python

Tags: python

How to access or use variable of one class in another class without creating their child class

Here is Code sample.

```
class A:
    def testA():
     self.a = "class A"

class B:
    def testB():
     **"Here I want to access self.a of class A"**
```

Comment: Actually your example makes it hard to tell exactly what you want to do. Do you want to access `~.a` as instance or class attribute ? Are you familiarized with the concepts of inheritance ? Composition ? Why do you your methods look static (without being so), etc...

Comment: @keepAlive I want to access value of **variable a**  initilized in function testA() in another class function testB().

Comment: You don't have a variable `a`. You have an attribute `a` of an instance of `A`. Local variables are just that: local to a function, not to be used outside. It doesn't make sense to talk about `testB` needing a local variable of another function, nor does it make sense to talk about needing an attribute of an instance without specifying *which* instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an instance of A to access its variables.

```
class A:
    def testA(self):
        self.a = "class A"

class B:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def testB(self):
        print(self.a.a)  # access the 'a' attribute of the local A class instance named 'a'

a = A()
a.testA()
b = B(a)  # <-- here
b.testB()
```

> without creating their child class

You are not using inheritance, so there is no "child class"